# WebService not displaying in browser

Tags: c#, web-services

I wanted to create and use a Web Service in VisualStudio2010.

So, all I did was:

> File->New Project->(.Net Framework3.5)Asp.NET WebService Application.

The hello world source page opened, I set visual studio development server, and the desired port, from properties and then I hit run. The problem is the page it is not opening. It is a connection problem or something.

Can you please tell me what do I have to do to make this webservice to run??

There are no error reports in visual or anything. It is just there is no display.

Comment: Did you check on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8wbhsy70%28v=vs.90%29.aspx). That would be the correct source to start.

Answer (score 0):

File->New Project->(.Net Framework3.5)Asp.NET WebService Application.

```
1.dont setup startup page.
2.run your webservice using green icon .
3.directory will be listed in browser.
4.select .svc file.
5.Your service is ready to execute.
```